# Garbled image problem on usb_cam

Tags: ros, usb-cam-node, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am testing usb_cam_node with a usb camera, when I use the follow launch file, everything is ok,

```
<launch>
<node name="camera" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen">
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="framerate" value="30" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap" />
    <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="file://$(find pixhawk)/launch/camera.yaml" />
</node>

<node name="viewer" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw" />
</node>
</launch>
```

but when I change pixel_format to **mjpeg**, the video become garbled

[garble1 http://s24.postimg.org/v9jlrwz4x/garble.png](http://s24.postimg.org/v9jlrwz4x/garble.png)
[tarble2 http://s24.postimg.org/i443lt59d/garbled2.png](http://s24.postimg.org/i443lt59d/garbled2.png)

`v4l2-ctl --list-format-ext -d /dev/video0` output:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Index       : 0
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
Name        : MJPEG
    Size: Discrete 1920x1080
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 1280x720
        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 1024x768
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 640x480
        Interval: Discrete 0.008s (120.101 fps)
    Size: Discrete 800x600
        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 1280x1024
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 320x240
        Interval: Discrete 0.008s (120.101 fps)

Index       : 1
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)
    Size: Discrete 1920x1080
        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 1280x720
        Interval: Discrete 0.111s (9.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 1024x768
        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 640x480
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 800x600
        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 1280x1024
        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 320x240
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

And the error message:

```
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] overread 8
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] overread 8
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error count: 68
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error y=38 x=1
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error count: 64
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error y=34 x=1
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error count: 68
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error y=40 x=4
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error count: 64
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error y=42 x=1
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error count: 64
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error y=31 x=0
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error count: 64
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] error y=30 x=37
[mjpeg @ 0x223e460] overread 8
```

My testing enviroment: Ubuntu 14.04.3, ROS indigo

I've search almost the whole web, can't figure it out, please help! Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217382/garbled-image-problem-on-usb_cam/) by [Allen Wong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23814/allen-wong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-09-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Allen!

I found that this problem is caused by linking wrong libraries. Try

```
ldd devel/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node
```

to see which lib is linked.

My ffmpeg was installed by apt-get from a ppa repository, the default location of such packages is /opt. But anyhow cmake didn't find the correct libavcodec and libswscale.

Later I install ffmpeg from source, install those libraries in /usr/local/lib, and manual set variable avcodec_LIBRARIES and INCLUDE_DIRS as:

```
## pkg-config libraries
# find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
# pkg_check_modules(avcodec libavcodec REQUIRED)
# pkg_check_modules(swscale libswscale REQUIRED)

set(avcodec_LIBRARIES /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57)
set(swscale_LIBRARIES /usr/local/lib/libswscale.so.4)
set(avcodec_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/include/libavcodec)
set(swscale_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/include/libswscale)
```

And, as the new version ffmpeg has changed some of its variable/function names, I have to modify the code of usb_cam.
Lucky, only a little at the begin of usb_cam.cpp:

```
#define avcodec_alloc_frame av_frame_alloc
#define PIX_FMT_RGB24 AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24
#define PIX_FMT_YUV422P AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P
```

Hope it helps!

---

Have you found the solution? I encountered exactly the same problem... the same ubuntu, the same indigo, my ffmpeg is something like:

```
ffmpeg version N-76045-g97be5d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

---

Originally posted by [taogashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20902/taogashi/) with karma: 26 on 2015-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EwingKang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19209/ewingkang/) on 2015-12-02**:
Hi, can you specify the detail of installing the ffmpeg from source? I've tried to do that with this link: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#ffmpeg but didn't come with success. The YUYV format just doesn't work with Full HD cameras (only 2 FPS!). Thanks!